# Make a new Table/Query out of Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Crosstab Query made out of an ODBC Table in MS-Access. The Query looks something like this with 4 fields containing Date. This Query is updated everyday and the empty fields may or may not be filled out

```
ANTRAGSNUMMER    Eingangdata   esigniertdok   Ausgangdata  Policierung

   111            3.10.2016 

   222            3.10.2016      3.10.2016

   333            4.10.2016      5.10.2016      5.10.2016
```

Now what I am trying to solve is to identify the records which have an empty field depending upon the following conditions

1. The record must be moved to a new Table/Query incase if the Field esigniertdok is empty for a record. It must check the date in the field Eingangdata (3.10.2016) and wait for 3 days from that date and if the Field esigniertdok is still empty then the record must be moved.
2. The record must be moved to a new Table/Query incase if the Field Ausgangdata is empty for a record. It must check the date in the field esigniertdok (3.10.2016) and wait for 2 days from that date and if the Field Ausgangdata is still empty then the record must be moved.
3. The record must be moved to a new Table/Query incase if the Field Policierung is empty for a record. It must check the date in the field Ausgangdata (5.10.2016) and wait for 5 days from that date and if the Field Policierung is still empty then the record must be moved.

How Can I do this? Is it possible to make a program in VBA and make all the records pass through it and verify the above conditions or is it possible to create a SQL query to do this?

The waiting time is different for different fields because each field is handled by a different departments. Also there are about 1000 records in the above pattern which are updated everyday.

Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: so what have you done so far? you could create new query with where condition like (date-3) > datevalue(Eingangdata) and (esigniertdok is null). This will answer your first question.

Comment: Datensatz = Record, not Recordset.

Comment: condition like (date-3) > datevalue(Eingangdata) and (esigniertdok is null) is not working. It doesn't show the records which are more than 3 days old from today.

Answer (score 0):

do you have 1000 recordsets or 1000 records in a recordset?

Let's try to understand you issue first. You say for example:

> The recordset must be moved to a new Table/Query incase if the Field esigniertdok is empty for a recordset. It must check the date in the field Eingangdata (3.10.2016) and wait for 3 days from that date and if the Field esigniertdok is still empty then the recordset must be moved.

Do you mean a record should be move to a new table if the Field esigniertdok is empty? If 3 days after the Eingangsdata (let's say 7.10.2016) the field "esigniertdok" is still empty, where it should be moved? Do you mean 'deleted' ?

UPDATE:

According to your comment you can use following code to copy data to a new table (let's name it: ESIGN) :

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
' CLEAR ALL ENTRIES FIRST
CurrentDb.Execute ("DELETE * FROM ESIGN")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [YOUR TABLE]")
Do Until rs.EOF
  If rs![esigniertdok] = "" Or IsNull(rs![esigniertdok]) Then
    If rs![Eingangdata] <= Date - 3 Then
        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO ESIGN (ANTRAGSNUMMER) VALUES (" & rs!ANTRAGSNUMMER & ")")
    End If
  End If
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Hi,  I have 1000 records in a recordset. You got it right if the esigniertdok is empty till when Eingangsdata is 7.10.2016 the record should be moved to a new table/query. It should not be deleted.